# Best way to use reflection

Tags: c#, optimization, reflection

My application pays a performance penalty because I'm using reflection, specifically to get attributes for classes and properties.

In order to optimize my application I want to generate a library that is based on the reflection but replacing it at runtime.

Today I use something like:

```
MyAttribute[] attributes = (MyAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CurrentNamespace.MyClass), typeof(MyAttribute));
var x = GetX(attributes);
```

I can generate a class with the same class name in a different namespace and call it statically.

```
MyReflectingClassInterface reflectingClass = getClassFromAssembly("ReflectingNamespace.MyClass");
var x = reflectingClass.getX(); // can't be static if I want to use interface.
```

Or,
Maybe the best way is to use one static switch:

```
static public X getX(Type type){
    if(type == typeof(CurrentNamespace.MyClass))
        return new X(5); // hard coded answer
}
```

Comment: Are you currently calling `GetCustomAttributes` frequently? Given that they're not going to change for a given class, you only need to call it once per class - then you can build a cache. That's likely to be significantly simpler than generating a class.

Comment: Why do you think you get performance issue because of using reflection? Indeed, it might cause it but what is your case?
Why do use attributes to get information about your classes? If it is only for your own code you can introduce an enum (flags). There're many options. If you tell us what you use them for, you might get better suggestions.

Comment: I have old and new versions of my REST API, for every call I check the request version in order to know if I can return the new standard or should I keep backward compatibility and return for each property name its old standard name. I keep the old name as an Attribute on each property. I also validate the REST inputs based of validation rules that I implemented as properties attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a static file that generated using reflection during the development, at runtime I just query this static class, it solved all performance issues.